# How to enforce Constraint in a created Table?

Tags: oracle

I am trying to figure out the correct constraint syntax for the following statement:

> "For a given site, either both the Catchment Area and Catchment Height must be specified, or neither of them are specified (i.e, either they are both NULL, or neither of them are NULL) - note this is a TABLE level constraint."

Catchment Area and Catchment Height are columns that I have in a Table.

What I have been doing so far is

1. Right Click on table name in the left pane to open "Edit Table"
2. Click "Edit"
3. Click on "Constraints" in the left pane
4. Click on the Green Plus > "New Check Constraint"

What this does open up a new text section in the "Edit Table" box called "Check Condition" where I have to specify the constraint in a syntax that Oracle SQL Developer can understand.

This method has worked so far with other constraints that I have enforced but for some reason I cannot figure out how to word this particular one.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

This is all happening in Oracle SQL Developer.

Comment: Like `CHECK ((CatchmentArea IS NULL AND CatchmentHeight IS NULL) OR (CatchmentArea IS NOT NULL AND CatchmentHeight IS NOT NULL))` ?

Comment: MySQL doesn't enforce CHECK constraints. Which DBMS is being used here? The question is tagged with Oracle, SQL Server and MySQL. If we need to enforce this kind of constraint in MySQL, we could do the check in BEFORE INSERT and BEFORE UPDATE triggers.

Comment: So similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44060363/how-to-enforce-a-constraint-in-a-table-already-created)...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the actual DDL

```
alter table your_table
    add constraint your_table_catchment_ck check 
    ( ( Catchment_Area is not null and Catchment_Height is not null)
      or ( Catchment_Area is null and Catchment_Height is null)
   )
```

For an IDE you just need to use the condition (the bit which follows `check`. Watch out for all the brackets!

Comment: Of course, the parentheses are not needed (technically; they may be needed for easier reading by humans). `(a and b) or (c and d)` is the same as `a and b or c and d`.

Comment: @mathguy - in my view, things which make it easier for humans to read code are as close to mandatory as makes no difference.

Comment: Agreed 100% - I was simply clarifying that point (that the parentheses are mandatory because they make the code easier to read, not because they are formally required).